# My Github contributions not showing up on graph with xcode 8

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode8

I created a project in Xcode (8.3.3) and put it on my Github account. But every commit I made using Xcode source control they never are show up on my contribution graph after I push my work. Does anyone have passed for this issue?

Ps. The commits are record normally.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, double-check your local config:

```
 git config user.name
 git config user.email
```

For your GitHub contribution to reflect your GitHub account, the user.name and user.email should be exactly the GitHub user name/email.

Then wait a bit: the contribution might not be updated right away.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode > Preferences > Source Control > Git

There you add your github email address and you all set!